# Best way to summarize a huge list of CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Suppose i have a table with a string and i want to create an aggregation of this table by grouping different string in a 'category'.
In order to understand to which category assign each string I have a list of possibilities that I could sum up as it follows:

CASE WHEN string = 'aaa' THEN 'cat_aaa'

CASE WHEN string = 'bbb' THEN 'cat_bbb'

[...]

CASE WHEN string LIKE '%abc%' THEN 'cat_abc'

Now, the list may be very huge and may needs update, so I don't want to make an infinite list of CASE WHEN. I'd like instead to have a table with the string used for the comparison and the corresponding category.

So let's suppose to have a first table with all the strings:

```
TABLE A
=======
string
--------
aaa
bbb
aaa
aaa
aaa
dabc
fabc
------
```

and another table

```
TABLE B
=======
string_comparison | category
      aaa         | cat_aaa
      bbb         | cat_bbb
     %abc%        | cat_abc
```

If they were all = condition, i could have just joined on the two strings. However, depending on the type of string_comparison, I may need to perform a LIKE comparison.
Do you have any fresh idea on how to solve this situation? I wouldn't like to join the two tables on a LIKE basis because of performances. Is there the possibility to use regular expressions on the string to solve this?

I am using redshift.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'd push back a bit on doing this in the database if it were my requirement, but if I HAD to,  I think I'd have a table with 3 columns, MATCH_OPERATOR (like, equals, startsWith, endsWith), MATCH_TEXT (your string comparison, without % signs), and CATEGORY, then use a sub select to grab the category as appropriate. Someone else can comment if they think that's a terrible idea  =)

Comment: @Nikki9696 how would you manage the situation differently? Consider that my inputs are the initial string that is already in a table on my database. Then I can create the input I prefer with the string_comparison and the associated category. A table sounded good for me, but since we cannot match any possible string_comparison I thought about the LIKE solution

Comment: @wellaDIN I'm usually not a fan of mixing business logic in with the persistence data layer. I'd store it differently (analyze required) and use the business layer (application code) to create the string like you do. I understand that this approach doesn't work in all situations though, so if it's not applicable for what your end goal is, then I'd use what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

A `like` without a wildcard is effectively the same as a `=`, and any reasonable optimizer should handle it properly, so I wouldn't try to overthink things and just try joining witha `like`:

```sql
SELECT   category, COUNT(*)
FROM     a
JOIN     b ON string LIKE string_comparison
GROUP BY category
```

If you're really concerned about the performance of the `like` operator you could try to check if the `string_comparison` doesn't have a wildcard in it and short-circuit it out, but I doubt it would be any faster than just using `like` directly:

```sql
SELECT   category, COUNT(*)
FROM     a
JOIN     b ON (POSITION('%' IN string_comparison) > 0 AND
               POSITION('_' IN string_comparison) > 0 AND 
               string LIKE string_coparison) OR
              string = string_comparison
GROUP BY category
```

Note: You didn't tag the question with the RDBMS you are using, so I gave an example using Postgresql's `position` function. Other RDBMSs should have functions with the same functionality, although their names may differ.

Comment: This sounds cool. However, another things that scares me about using the LIKE operator is that it may (even if this should not be possible) give me more rows as a result, while the EQUALS will not (assuming string_comparison is key for table B). Do you think there is a way to handle this situation and possible duplicates?